# Front end HTML using the Django template

Tags: python, html, django

I have written this view in Django to display a list of movie names.

```
def index(request):
    latest_movie_list = MoviesDB.objects.values('movie_name').distinct()
    t = loader.get_template('movies/index.html')
    c = Context({
        'latest_movie_list': latest_movie_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Then I have written a template as below.

```
{% if latest_movie_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for movie in latest_movie_list %}
        <li>
        <a href="/movies/{{ movie.id }}/">{{ movie.movie_name }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% emdif %}
```

Now how do I need to write a front end HTML for this?

Please see the below code I wrote.

```
<html>
<head><title>Home</title></head>
<body>
<ul>
How to get the movie names returned by the view to display here..?
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In Django, the template code is integrated with the html code.

Comment: How do we do the integration? I suspect I need to write something there between <ul> and </ul> that makes the HTML integrate with that of the template code.

Comment: well, you place the "template" inside your body tags, and you should have a finished `template`

Answer (score 1):

You can include the template into your HTML file by using the `include` tag. e.g.

```
{% include movie_list_template %}
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include)

Answer (score 1):

base

```
<html>
<head><title>Home</title></head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

movie_list

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% if latest_movie_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for movie in latest_movie_list %}
        <li>
        <a href="/movies/{{ movie.id }}/">{{ movie.movie_name }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "integration". The Django template *is* HTML. The other template is HTML too. If you want your list of movies to appear between the `ul` tags in the main template, then just put that code there.

(Eventually, you'll need to learn about template inheritance, but since you seem confused at the first step that's probably too far for now.)